# Laravel Echo private channel not listening

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am trying to create a real-time chat application. I used Laravel Echo, Redis, and socket-io.

But `laravel-echo` is not listening to private broadcast chat channel.

`App\Events\MessagePushed`

```php
public function broadcastAs()
{
  return 'new.message';
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
  return new PrivateChannel("application-chat-{$this->message->job_application_id}");
}
```

`routes/channels.php`

```php
Broadcast::channel('application-chat-{job_application_id}', function ($user, $job_application_id) {
    return auth()->check();
});
```

`Store Message resource method`

```php
public function store(StoreFormRequest $request, JobApplication $application)
{
   $request->merge([
      'sender_id' => $request->user()->id,
   ]);

   $message = $application->messages()->create($request->all())
                          ->load(['sender', 'receiver']);

   event(new MessagePushed($message));

   return response()->json([
      'message' => $message,
   ]);
}
```

`Listening to private channel`

```
window.Echo.private(`application-chat-${this.messageApplication}`)
      .listen('.new.message', (data) => {
          console.clear();
         console.log('Got event...', data);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried pointing the event directly? .listen('MessagePushed')

Comment: I've tried, no changes

Comment: What are you using as socket provider?

Comment: I'm using Redis as a message broadcast.

Comment: If I am not wrong.. that is fine, but you still need something that will send those to users. Take a look at beyondcode/laravel-websockets & tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server

Comment: what errors are you getting on your node server?

Comment: There are no errors, even in Logs.

Comment: check in the laravel echo server config if your authHost has the same port as your laravel application, also verify if the BroadcastServiceProvider is uncommented in the providers  ( config/app.php )

Comment: I've checked everything is OK, I did that in the first settings․

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I also encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help to debug:

**Laravel echo server config:**

```
{
    "authHost": "domain.local",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {}
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

**php artisan queue:work:**

Check that queue sends events

[image]

**laravel echo server**

Check that user joins channel and echo server sends events

[image]

**Laravel Echo:**

Maybe problem with broacastAs. Try to not use it. Don't forget to add namespace property to config.

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    namespace: 'App.Events',
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: //auth
        }
    }
});
```

Name of Event = Name of Event class

```
window.Echo.private(`application-chat-${this.messageApplication}`)
    .listen('MessagePushed', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the namespace

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    namespace: 'App.Events',
});
```